# How to find adding reference is needed with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have added some 'StatementSyntax' into MethodDeclarationSyntax and I saved that to real Solution. When I opened the solution with VS it doesn't run because I must add some references from other projects in my solution and from .Net.I want to  know can I find with roslyn that which reference and using  is needed to add to project and c# file and how add these references programmatically  if yes how?

Comment: `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.*` _is_ Roslyn.

Comment: I mean that name space Roslyn.*

Comment: That's the two-year old preview build.  Don't use that.

Comment: I used that because I don't know how  load solution and project and save that to real Solution with Microsoft. CodeAnalysis

Comment: You're looking for `MSBuildWorkspace`.

Comment: Does MSBuildWorkspace is working with roslyn?

Comment: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs

Comment: MSBuild is a part of Roslyn...?